# Resources For Learning Southwestern Mandarin (西南官话)

Tags: topolect, resources

We already have:

- [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese?rq=1)
- [Useful resources for learning Taiwanese?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/118/useful-resources-for-learning-taiwanese?rq=1)
- [Resources for learning Cantonese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/resources-for-learning-cantonese)
- [Resources for learning Shanghainese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/resources-for-learning-shanghainese)
- [Resources for learning classical Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/305/resources-for-learning-classical-chinese)

Here's what [Wikipedia: Southwestern Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southwestern_Mandarin) has to say about it:

> Southwestern Mandarin (simplified Chinese: 西南官话; traditional Chinese: 西南官話; pinyin: Xīnán Guānhuà), also known as Upper Yangtze Mandarin (simplified Chinese: 上江官话; traditional Chinese: 上江官話; pinyin: Shàngjiāng Guānhuà), is a primary branch of Mandarin Chinese spoken in much of central and southwestern China, including in Sichuan, Yunnan, Chongqing, Guizhou, most parts of Hubei, the northwestern part of Hunan, the northern part of Guangxi, and some southern parts of Shaanxi and Gansu.
>
> Varieties of Southwestern Mandarin are spoken by roughly 200 million people. If removed from the larger "Mandarin Chinese group", it would have the 6th-most native speakers in the world, behind Mandarin, Spanish, English, Hindi, and Bengali.

For a language with so many speakers there seems to be very little resources for learning such a language.

As far as **dictionaries** go I'm aware of the following:

《[四川方言词语汇释](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yOwnAAAAMAAJ&q=%E5%9B%9B%E5%B7%9D%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E8%AF%8D%E8%AF%AD%E6%B1%87%E9%87%8A&dq=%E5%9B%9B%E5%B7%9D%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E8%AF%8D%E8%AF%AD%E6%B1%87%E9%87%8A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMIqdeq6JPkxgIVjlmOCh3fGQB-)》

《[成都话方言词典](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjABahUKEwjOrZuhk-TGAhXGUo4KHWWzA2o&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbooks.google.com%2Fbooks%2Fabout%2F%25E6%2588%2590%25E9%2583%25BD%25E8%25AF%259D%25E6%2596%25B9%25E8%25A8%2580%25E8%25AF%258D%25E5%2585%25B8.html%3Fid%3Dm90nAAAAMAAJ&ei=Uv-pVc68F8aluQTl5o7QBg&usg=AFQjCNHF_j2ttdq99INc1tSKfyu3RYjpmw&sig2=gFyLxYlQZLp6j9-dK5Yywg&bvm=bv.98197061,d.dGY)》

《[四川方言词典](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/%E5%9B%9B%E5%B7%9D%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8.html?id=p-C6AAAAIAAJ)》

《[成都方言词典](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ds8SAQAAMAAJ&q=%E6%88%90%E9%83%BD%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8&dq=%E6%88%90%E9%83%BD%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAWoVChMI1fjJu5PkxgIVWI-OCh0FtQTD)》

《[蜀籁](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/%E8%9C%80%E7%B1%9F.html?id=mGMKAAAAMAAJ)》

《四川方言词语汇编》

What resources are available for learners of Southwestern Mandarin?

Comment: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2602/are-there-online-resources-for-learning-the-chongqing-dialect/2604#2604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michaelyus's answer to a similar question (link in the comments above) is still very useful.

A general resource that unfortunately may be hard to find now is the 現代方言音庫, a series published by the 上海教育出版社 in the mid 1990s.  This series consisted of a thin booklet titled XX音檔 (usu 100-150 pages) and a good quality cassette for each dialect. The series eventually covered 40 plus dialects, including 成都，貴陽，and 昆明, and the booklets were often written by well-known experts; for example, 成都話音檔 was written by the late 崔榮昌，who did much important work on 四川 dialects. In addition to characters, pronunciation is given in IPA, which I found *very* helpful.

One problem there may be in making a list of resources for 西南官話 is that it includes a large range of sometimes pretty different dialects.  For example, the varieties spoken in Hubei are sharply different to my ears from 成都 and 昆明.

Comment: is this the audio for 成都 http://www.tudou.com/programs/view/G-62lx3uMtk/?resourceId=64267208_06_02_99 ？

Comment: Yep, that's her.

Comment: I was able to grab two f4v files off of tudou one clocks in at about 26 min the other at about 24 min, that should be both sides of the cassette, right?

Comment: Right.  After listening, it does seem like it would be useful to have a copy of the book at hand to understand all these minimal pairs the first side gives.  The second side is more fun.  Interesting that ALL the tapes I've heard in this series use "The north wind and the sun" for the extended oral material.  Chao Yuen-ren and his students used this in all their surveys, starting in the 1920s, and apparently it's still a universally known story.

Comment: It might be here:
http://page.renren.com/601156222/note/927693036
I haven't registered a ren ren so I don't know what's hidden underneath!

Answer (score 0):

tudou: [1](http://www.tudou.com/v/G-62lx3uMtk/&resourceId=0_04_05_99/v.swf)

tudou: [2](http://www.tudou.com/v/Ll_7-tcOHIU/&resourceId=0_04_05_99/v.swf)

**Transcript**:

本文限於成都城区中派音系，敬请期待兼容成都与四川盆地各县市现代方音的四川话拼音方案。正文基本选自《成都话音档》录音。文中拼音的加粗字體為聲調和韻母等同普通話有明顯區別的部分。

一、语音

1.1 声母

b [p] 帮bāng 巴bā 不bû 
p [p'] 滂pâng 怕pá 扑pû 
m [m] 明mîn 妈mā 木mû 
f [f] 非fēi 奉fóng 胡fû

d [t] 端duān 大dá 达dâ
t [t'] 透tóu 他tā 托tô 
l [l~n] 南兰lân 腊lâ

z [ts] 资知zī 照záo
c [ts'] 雌cî 彻cê 穿cuān

s [s] 苏书sū 生sēn
r [z] 日rî 热rê 人rên

j [tɕ] 精jīn 见jián 积jî 
q [tɕ'] 清qīn 溪qī 七qî 
n [ȵ] 泥疑nî 捏niē（文读niê）
x [ɕ] 希西xī 昔xî

g [k] 高gāo 狗gòu 各gô 
k [k'] 敲kāo 口kòu 可kò
ng [ŋ] 熬ngâo 藕ngòu 我ngò
h [x] 好hào 后hóu 合hô

〇　衣yī 鱼yû 五wù

1.2 声母比字

1)　酒=九jiù　清=轻qīn　鲜=掀xuān
2)　怒=路lú　恼=老lào　南=兰lân
3)　你nì≠李lì　女nǜ≠旅lǜ　牛niû≠流liû
4)　呼=夫fū　胡=扶fû　虎=府fù　戶=富fú
5)　资=知zī　疵=痴cī　思=诗sī
6)　鹅=俄ô　饿=卧ngó　艾=爱ngái

1.3 韵母

i (空韵) [ɿ] 子zì 池cî 日rî 
i [i] 基jī 西xī 一yî 
u [u] 布bú 古gù 屋wû 
ü [y] 居jū 徐xû 玉yú

er [əɻ] 而êr 耳èr 二ér

a [a] 巴bā 大dá 杀sâ 
ia [ia] 家jiā 霞xiâ 鸭yâ 
ua [ua] 瓜guā 花huā 袜wâ

o [o] 波bō 歌gō 说sô 
io [yo] 略liô 族qiô 育yô

e [e] 北bê 热rê 客kê 
ie [ie] 别biê 踢tiê（文读tî） 爷yê 
ue [ue] 郭guê 括kuê 获huê 
üe [ye] 绝juê 缺quê 月yuê

ai [ai] 拜bái 街gāi 鞋hâi
iai [iai] 阶jiāi 谐xiâi 延yâi 
uai [uai] 乖guāi 怀huâi 外wái

ei [ei] 悲bēi 批pēi 肥fêi

uei [uei] 堆duī 雷luî 水suì

ao [au] 包bāo 桃tâo 咬ngào（文读niào）
iao [iau] 表biào 巧qiào 小xiào

ou [əu] 头tôu 首sòu 欧ngōu
iou [iəu] 柳liù 秋qiū 柚yóu

an [an] 般bān 谈tân 安ngān
ian [ian] 边biān 田tiân 年niân
uan [uan] 团tuân 川cuān 欢huān
üan [yan] 泉quân 选xuàn 员yuân

en [ən] 崩bēn 恩ngēn 生sēn
in [in] 丙bìn 清qīn 心xīn
uen [uən] 昆kūn 春cūn 文wên
ün [yn] 君jūn 旬xûn 荣yûn

ang [aŋ] 帮bāng 场câng 康kāng
iang [iaŋ] 良liâng 想xiàng 央yâng
uang [uaŋ] 双suāng 黄huâng 旺wáng

ong [oŋ] 朋pông 孔kòng 翁ōng
iong [yoŋ] 穷qiông 兄xiōng 蓉yông

1.4 韵母比字

1) 族屈雀qiô　俗蓄学xiô　育约yô
2) 客kê≠课kó　核hê≠河hô　额ngê≠鹅ô
3) 锅gō≠郭guê　桌zô≠拙zuê　货hó≠获huê
4) 些xī≠歇xiê　携xī≠邪xiê≠鞋hâi　接jiê≠街gāi　姐jiè≠解jiài
5) 贫平pîn　民明mîn　今京jīn
6) 奔崩bēn　盆彭pên　森生孙sēn　针争尊zēn
7) 郡窘jùn　群琼qûn　允永yùn
8) 迫pê≠培pêi　墨mê≠梅mêi
9) 阔kuê≠逵kuî　或huê≠回huî

1.5 声调

1) ā 阴平45　专zuān 开kāi 天tiān 三sān
2) â 阳平31　陈cên 唐tâng 寒hân 月yuê
3) à 上声53　古gù 口kòu 好hào 五wù
4) á 去声213　近jín 厚hóu 抗káng 害hái

四个声调的五度调值参考自http://photo.renren.com/photo/277665350/album-385379739?frommyphoto

1.6 声调比字

阴平和阳平：之zī≠织zî　衣yī≠一yî　沙sā≠杀sâ
阳平和上声：谷gû≠古gù　蜀sû≠暑sù　甲jiâ≠假jià
阳平和去声：作zô≠坐zó　握ô≠卧(ng)ó　葉yê≠夜yé

1.7 变调

阳平叠字後字近似阴平：瓶瓶ㄦ　盆盆ㄦ　壳壳　雀雀
去声叠字後字近似阴平：棍棍　洞洞　棒棒　柜柜
上声叠字後字近似阳平：本本　桶桶　米米　姐姐

前字阳平後字近似阴平：头髮　核桃　钥匙　喉咙
前字去声後字近似阴平：薄荷　四季豆

1.8 文白异读词比较举例

下　文xiá ～降，～午　白há 等一～，去一～
解　文jiài 讲～　白gài ～开
敲　文qiāo 推～　白kāo ～门
锯　文jú ～子　白gé ～一刀

1.9 儿化词举例

凉粉ㄦliângfèr　杯杯ㄦbēibēr　娃娃ㄦwâwer　花生米ㄦhuāsēnmìr　蛐蟮ㄦqûsér

1.10 发音练习

声母

泥牛nîniû　扭捏niùniê　研究niānjiú
恩爱ngēnngái　雁鹅ngánngô　肮脏ngāngzāng

韵母

唱歌cánggō　科学kōxiô　委屈wèiqiô　教育jiáoyô 
北京Bêjīn　压迫yápê　来去lâiqié（去字文读qú）　集体jîtì　国家guêjiā　收获sōuhuê 
解放jiàifáng　世界síjiái

声调

阴阳上去Yīn Yâng Sàng Qú　非常美丽fēisâng mèilí　英雄好汉yīnxiông hàohán　巴蜀锦绣Bāsû jìnxiú

二、常用词汇（暂略）

三、构词法举要（暂略）

四、语法例句

Làgó? Ngò sí Lào Sān.
1) 哪个？我是老三。

Lào Sí nān? Tā zénzái gēn yî gó pôngyòu sô dào huá lī.
2) 老四喃？她正在跟一个朋友说倒话的（文读dî）。

Tā hâi méiyou sô wân â?
3) 她还（文读huân）没有说完啊？

Hâi méiyou. Dáyô hâi yòu yî hēr jiú sô wân lò.
4) 还没（文读mû）有。大约还有一下ㄦ就说完了（文读liào）。

Tā jiàng màsáng jiú zòu, zâgó zénmen jiù lò hâi zái wûtôu lē?
5) 他讲马上就走，咋个这门久了还在屋头呢？

Nì zòu lèr qié? Ngò dáo cēn hòutôu qié.
6) 你走哪ㄦ去？我到城後（文读hóu）头去。

Zái lēr, bû zái zēr. / ... lálì ...... zélì.
7) 在那ㄦ，不在这ㄦ。／在那里，不在这里。

Bû sí lá yángzì zú, yáo zé yángzì zú.
8) 不是那样子做，要这样子做。

Tái dō lô, yóng bû dào lámen dō, zìyáo zénmen dō jiú góu lô.
9) 太多了，用不倒那门多，只要这门多就够了。

Zégo dá, lágo xiào, zé liànggó làyîgó hào (yî) dìr?
10) 这个大，那个小，这两个哪一个好(一)点ㄦ？

Zégo gàn (bì) lágo hào.
11) 这个赶(比)那个好。

Zéxī fângzì môde láxī fângzì hào.
12) 这些房子莫得那些房子好。

Zé jú huá yóng Cêndū huá zâgó sô?
13) 这句话用成都话咋个说？

Tā jīnniân hào dá suísú lô? / ......
14) 他今年好大岁数了？／他今年好多岁了？

Pá yòu sānsî sángxiá lô. / ...... lâiwàng lô.
15) 怕有三十上下了。／怕有三十来往了。

Zégó dōngxī yòu hào zóng?
16) 这个东西有好重？

Yòu wùsî jīn zóng ó.
17) 有五十斤重哦。

Lào dêqì bû? / ......
18) 㧯得起不？／㧯不㧯得起？

Ngò lào dêqì, tā lào bûqì.
19) 我㧯得起，他㧯不起。

Ngénsí bû qīn ô, zóng dê liân ngò dōu lào bûqì.
20) 硬是不轻哦，重得连我都㧯不起。

Nì sô dê hào hào, nì hâi huí sô dìr sázì lē?
21) 你说得好好，你还会说点ㄦ啥子呢？

Ngò zuìbā bén, ngò jiàng bû yîn tā. / ......
22) 我嘴巴笨，我讲不赢他。／我讲他不赢。

Sô lò yî dáo, yóu sô yî dáo. / ..... yî huî ......
23) 说了一道，又说一道。／讲了一回，又讲一回。

Qìn nì zái sô yî dáo.
24) 请你再说一道。

Bû zào lò, kuái dìr qié.
25) 不早了，快点ㄦ去。

Zéher hâi zào, dèn háher zái qié mâ. / Zé zén ...... gó yî zén ......
26) 这下ㄦ还早，等下下ㄦ再去嘛。／这阵还早，过一阵再去嘛。

Cî lò fán zái qié yáodê bû?
27) 吃了饭再去要得不？

Mánmer cî, bûyáo huāng. / ...... zâojî.
28) 慢慢ㄦ吃，不要慌。／不要着（文读zô）急。

Zó dào cî bì zán dào cî hào xī.
29) 坐倒吃比站倒吃好些。

Tā cî lò fán lò, nì cî lò fán mēiyòu? / ......
30) 他吃了饭了，你吃了饭没有？／他吃（了饭）了，你吃了（饭）没有？

Tā qié gó Sánghài, ngò mēi qié gó. / Tā dáo ...
31) 他去过上海，我没去过。／他到过上海，我没到过。

Lâi wên házì zé dò huā xiāng bû xiāng.
32) 来闻下子这朵花香不香。

Gē ngò (yî) bèn sū. / Lá bèn sū gē ngò.
33) 跟（文读gēn）我(一)本书。／拿本书跟我。

Ngò ngénsí môde lá bèn sū.
34) 我硬是莫得那本书。

Nì gēn tā sô. / Nì gē tā jiàng. / Nì duí tā jiàng.
35) 你跟他说。／你跟他讲。／你对他讲。

Hàosēn zòu, bûyáo pào. / Hàohàosēnsēn ......
36) 好声走，不要跑。／好好声声走，不要跑。

Xiàoxīn bán dào lò pâ bû qìlâi.
37) 小心跘倒了爬不起来。

Yīsēn hàn nì dō suí hēr. / ...... kún hēr.
38) 医生喊你多睡下ㄦ。／医生喊你多睏下ㄦ。

Cîyān cîcâ dōu bû zùn.
39) 吃菸吃茶都不准。

Yān hô câ, ngò dōu bû xìhuān.
40) 菸和茶，我都不喜欢。

Bû guàn nì qié bû qié, hûnsún ngò sí yáo qié lī.
41) 不管你去不去，横顺我是要去的。

Ngò jiúsí yáo qié. / ... yîdín ......
42) 我就是要去。／我一定要去。

Nì sí làyî niân lâi lī?
43) 你是哪一年来的？

Ngò sí qiân niânzì dáo Bêjīn lī.
44) 我是前年子到北京的。

Jīntiān kāihuí làgó dāng zùxî?
45) 今天开会哪个当主席？

Qìnkê. / Qìn cî tâng. / Qìn cî xìjiù. / Bán zāodái. / Nì yáo qìn ngò ó.
46) 请客。／请吃糖。／请吃喜酒。／办招待。／你要请我噢。

Yîbiān zòu, yîbiān bài. / ......
47) 一边走，一边摆。／边走边摆。

Yuê zòu yuê yuàn, yuê bài yuê dō.
48) 越走越远，越摆越多。

Bà lágo dōngxī lâ gē ngò. / ...... lào gē ...
49) 把那个东西拿跟我。／把那个东西㧯跟我。

Yòuli dífāng bà táiyâng jiáozô rîtôu.
50) 有的地方把太阳叫作日头。

Nì guíxín? Ngò xín Wâng.
51) 你贵姓？我姓王。

Nì xín Wâng, ngò yè xín Wâng, ngòmen liànggó dōu xín Wâng.
52) 你姓王我也姓王，我们两个都姓王。

Nì xiān qié mâ, ngòmen dènher jiú lâi.
53) 你先去嘛，我们等下ㄦ就来。

Nì cîbûcî yân? / ......
54) 你吃不吃菸？你吃菸不？

Nì rénbûrén dêdào lágó rên? / ......
55) 你认不认得倒那个人？／你认得倒那个人吗？

Ngò mèi huîlâi dōu jiándào nì.
56) 我每回来都见倒你。

Zé jián sí hào fāng rên.
57) 这件事好方人。

Nì bû xín jiú gáo yî pêr.
58) 你不信就较（文读jiáo）一盘ㄦ。

Ngò jiàng lī díérlī yîdiàn jí dào mēiyòu?
59) 我讲的第二的一点记倒没有？

Tā duí rên zìyòu lámen hào lò.
60) 他对人只有那门好了。

五、长篇语料

BÊFŌNG Gēn TÁIYÂNG

北风跟太阳

Yòu huîzì, Bêfōng gēn táiyâng zái lēr zēn làyîgólī bènsí dá.
有回子，北风跟太阳在那ㄦ争哪一个的本事大。

Zēn gólâi zēn góqié jiúsí fēn bû cû gāongài.
争过来争过去就是分不出高矮。

Yîher lúsáng lâilò yîgó gànlú lī, 
一下ㄦ路上来了一个赶路的，

Tā sēnsáng cuāndào yîjián hóu dáyī.
他身上穿倒一件厚大衣。

Tāmen liànggó xiān jiàng hào lò, 
他们两个先讲好了，

Kán làgó lêngóu xiān jiáo zégó gànlú lī tôxiá tālī hóu dáyī, 
看哪个能够先叫这个赶路的脱下他的厚大衣，

jiú suán làgólī bènsí dá.
就算哪个的本事大。

Bêfōng jiú zànjínlī cuī qìlâi, xiàodê bû, 
北风就撍劲的吹起来，晓得不，

tā cuī dê yuê xiōng, lágó gànlú lī bà dáyī gò dê yuê jìn.
他吹得越凶，那个赶路的把大衣裹得越紧。

Hóulâi lê, Bêfōng môde fâ lò, jiú zìhào suánlò.
後来呢，北风莫得法了，就只好算了。

Gó lò yîzén, Táiyâng góng cûlâi lò.
过了一阵，太阳贡出来了。

Tā hòpiàopiàolī yî sái, lágó gànlú lī màsáng jiú bà lá jián hóu dáyī tô lò.
他火熛熛的一晒，那个赶路的马上就把那件厚大衣脱了。

Zé zénzì Bêfōng zìdê rénsū, 
这阵子北风只得认输，

tāmen liànggó zōngjiān hâisí Táiyâng lī bènsí dá.
他们两个中间还是太阳的本事大。

附：声韵调的音节改写规则

儿化韵母按四呼分别为er ier uer üer，如猫ㄦmēr，鸡ㄦjīr，花ㄦhūr，圈ㄦqūr
i、u、ü和以三者之一起首的韵母，在零声母後的改写方式与普通话标凖汉语拼音相仿，如衣yī 丫yā 因yīn 乌wū 威wēi 迂yū 冤yuān 晕yūn
ü和以ü起首的韵母在j q x後改写为u，如居ju
iou uei uen ier uer üer在非零声母後省略主元音，如牛niû，归guī
在不方便输入输出修饰字母的场合，阴平、阳平、上声、去声依次可用1~4在音节末尾编号代替修饰符号，比如山盟海誓sanmonghaisi1234，打电话da3 dian4hua4
音节的界限在必要情况使用隔音符号(')隔开，如西翁xi'ong

(≧▽≦)/(≧▽≦)/(≧▽≦)/(≧▽≦)/(分割线)/(≧▽≦)/(≧▽≦)/(≧▽≦)/(≧▽≦)/

参考文献

侯精一主编；崔荣昌编写；萧娅曼发音 方舟解说. 成都话音档. 上海市：上海教育出版社, 1997
表情

Comment: So this guy wants to invent his own "pinyin" system for Chengdu hua.  The characters seem to be from the book, but the book uses real IPA.  There are some other changes too.  For example, in the book's 1.5, it gives the tones as 55, 31, 53, 13.  This guy changes it to  43, 31, 53, 213. I guess you can listen for yourself, but don't take everything he's got here as coming from 崔荣昌.

Comment: I always thought it was 55, 21, 53, 213, but I got that from 成都话方言词典

Comment: @wpt can you see the photo linked? http://photo.renren.com/photo/277665350/album-385379739?frommyphoto 

i only get "您没有操作本资源的权限"

Comment: No, it's asking me to register. Argh, I'd rather not.

Comment: Don't. I registered and still can't see it